# Rolling underwater results in: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quantitative-finance, rolling-computation

I'm attempting to compute the rolling yearly underwater and it leads to the `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`. This is a self contained toy MRE example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate random returns for two assets
dfr = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random_sample((10, 2)),
                   columns=['a', 'b'])
print(dfr)

# compute rolling underwater
dfu = dfr.rolling(5, axis=0).apply(lambda x: x / x.cummax() - 1.0)
print(dfu)
```

Comment: Can you add expected output? e.g. if `np.random.seed(42)`

Comment: I think problem is rolling need aggregate output, so e.g. working well `lambda x: (x / x.cummax() - 1.0).sum())`

Comment: @jezrael do you think you could make an answer? It seems useful for the OP and future occasions too.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - I try do some research first ;)

Comment: Ah okay, I tested the code in my computer and it worked perfect, that's why :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher - ya, but it was only example, not sure what OP need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now in pandas [rolling.apply is possible return only scalar](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4130#issuecomment-403153496), like here if add some aggregation, e.g. `max`:

```
dfu = dfr.rolling(5, axis=0).apply(lambda x: (x / x.cummax() - 1.0).max())
```

After some research if possible use `max` - aggregation return scalar, instead `cummax` return array in each iteration:

```
dfu = dfr.rolling(5, axis=0).max().sub(1.0).rdiv(dfr)
print(dfu)
          a         b
0       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN
4  4.592909  2.918181
5  0.028935       inf
6       inf  0.280289
7  0.279465  0.233189
8  0.575998  1.178822
9  1.078521  0.429111
```

You can test how working your solution with this trick:

```
def f(x):
    print (x / x.cummax() - 1.0)
    return x.sum()

dfu = dfr.rolling(5, axis=0).apply(f)
```

And one possible idea how convert output to `DataFrame`:

```
dfr =pd.concat( [(x / x.cummax() - 1.0) for x in dfr.rolling(5, axis=0)])
```

Comment: @SkyWalker - oops, it should be `1.0`.  It is only some idea for working solution, but not 100% sure if need this.